# Morphia Add item to embedded

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have the following structures.
Products is embedded in Store; and reviews is embedded in product.

```
1- Store
  2-Products[]-->
     3-Reviews[]
```

I am trying to add a new item to review with the following code. It doesn't give me an error but neither does it add it.

```
Query q1=ds.createQuery(Product.class).filter("Code", code);
if(q1.countAll()==1)
    {
    ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(Product.class).add("Reviews", review);
    ds.update(q1, ops);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The only was is query for the embedded product, modified it by adding a new review and update that product with ds.CreateUpdateOperations().Set(ops)